# After scroll not calling load more function in infinite scroll

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, infinite-scroll, nginfinitescroll, jquery-infinite-scroll

I'm developing application with Angular material.

Same code work with angular application but does not work with angular material.

**Here is my controller code**

```
   $scope.casesData = [];
   var casesData = {};

   $scope.first = 0;
   $scope.last = 20;



    var onResponse = function(response){        
        casesData = response;   
        $scope.loadMore();
    };
    $scope.loadMore = function () {
            for ($scope.first; $scope.first < $scope.last; $scope.first++) {
                if(casesData[$scope.first] !== undefined)
                    $scope.casesData.push(casesData[$scope.first]);
            }
            $scope.last = $scope.last + 20;
    };
```

**Here is my view code**

```
<div infinite-scroll="loadMore()" infinite-scroll-distance="3" infinite-scroll-immediate-check="false">
       <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in casesData">
                <div>
                   //Do some stuff
                </div>
                <!-- Recent records listing -->
                <md-item class="item" ng-repeat="case in value track by case.index_no" ng-class="">
                //Do some stuff
               </md-item>
    </div>
 </div>
```

After successful request I'm sending response to the **onResponse()** function. First time it's giving me 20 records but when I scroll down the page **`it's not calling the loadMore()` function from view**

Same type of example I implemented in angular js only it's working but don't know Why this is not working with angular material.

Please help me out from this stuff.

Comment: If you're working with Angular Material I would consider ditching jquery-infinite-scroll and using md-virtual-repeat. https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat

Comment: Thanks @MikeFeltman

Comment: Did you find a solution ?
I'm stuck with the same problem, I don't use material